# How to overcome Recurssion Error for the Trigger firing more then once

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger RecursionPrevention on Account (after insert,after update)
 {
 Account acct = Trigger.new[0];
String accountid = acct.id;
 System.debug('Calling');

 if(!RecursionBooleanClass.hasAlreadyfired()){
System.debug('Calling--1');

 Map<Id, Account> accountMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
 for(Opportunity opp : [Select Id,Name,Type,Amount,AccountId,height__c,CloseDate,StageName,Expected_Revenue__c,Sameer__c From Opportunity where StageName = 'Prospecting' and AccountId =: accountid  ])
 {
 System.debug('Calling--2::'+opp);
 Account acct1 = new Account(Id=opp.AccountId, Rating = 'Hot', height__c = opp.height__c);
 AccountMap.put(acct1.Id, acct1);
 }
 if(accountMap.size()>0) 
   {

       update accountMap.values();


   }
}
RecursionBooleanClass.setAlreadyfired();

}
```

following is the class

```
public  class RecursionBooleanClass {

public static boolean firstRun = false;  




     public static boolean hasAlreadyfired() {
        return firstRun;
    }

    public static void setAlreadyfired() {
        firstRun = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Working code`

```
trigger RecursionPrevention on Account(after insert, after update) {
    Account acct = Trigger.new[0];
    String accountid = acct.id;
    System.debug('Calling');

    if (!RecursionBooleanClass.hasAlreadyfired()) {
        //Change here
        RecursionBooleanClass.setAlreadyfired();

        System.debug('Calling--1');
        Map accountMap = new Map();
        for (Opportunity opp: [Select Id, Name, Type, Amount, AccountId, height__c, CloseDate, StageName, Expected_Revenue__c, Sameer__c From Opportunity where StageName = 'Prospecting'
                and AccountId =: accountid]) {
            System.debug('Calling--2::' + opp);
            Account acct1 = new Account(Id = opp.AccountId, Rating = 'Hot', height__c = opp.height__c);
            AccountMap.put(acct1.Id, acct1);
        }
        if (accountMap.size() > 0) {
            update accountMap.values();
        }
    }
}
```

Set recursion varible before update operation on record.

`RecursionBooleanClass.setAlreadyfired();`

Comment: Static boolean is not the best way of handling this, a set of ids is better. The boolean will be set to true to in a bulk transaction for anything after the first batch.